# Why does flow_from_directory and image_dataset_from_directory returns completely different validation results?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, imagedatagenerator

I am training a mobilenet, evaluation metrics are consistently low so I am trying different ways of loading the dataset, so I tried both the methods

Below are the codes I used:

```
train_datagen=ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,
                                 horizontal_flip=False)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator=train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    '/home/kun/knee/train/', 
    target_size=(128,128),
    color_mode='rgb',
    batch_size=16 ,
    class_mode='categorical')

test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    '/home/kun/knee/test/',
    target_size=(128,128),
    color_mode='rgb',
    batch_size=16,
    class_mode='categorical',
    shuffle=False)
```

When I use ImageDataGenerator, things went well only that precision is low even validation accuracy is high and it takes 270 seconds for each epoch (big dataset 4000+ images)

Then I tried this:

```
train_ds = image_dataset_from_directory(
    directory='/home/kun/knee/train/',
    labels='inferred',
    label_mode='categorical',
    batch_size=16,
    image_size=(128, 128))
validation_ds = image_dataset_from_directory(
    directory='/home/kun/knee/test/',
    labels='inferred',
    label_mode='categorical',
    batch_size=16,
    image_size=(128, 128))
```

Time for each epoch only about 80 seconds. But this time the confusion matrix came out and it looks like this:
[cm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tywIm.png)

All the testing images are predicted to 1 class (sorry I dont know how to make the image appear directly in this post please click)

Can anyone shed some lights about this? I would really like to use image_dataset_from_directory if possible because of it speeds up the process

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

okay so I think I found an answer to this after trolling through everything I can find online.

Basically, if I wanna use image_dataset_from_directory, I need to rescale (preprocess) the images before training.

What I did is adding an additional rescale layer on top of my model.

I am still not sure if both methods actually return different types of data that is input into the model, which probably causes confusion during the prediction stage, but I can be sure that this problem has nothing to do with learning rate, batch size, and dataset shuffling.

Maybe this will help save some time for other people out there with the same problem that I am.